# Reactive Form Validation Error in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the Reactive form Validation code but I got an error. Here is my code. Did I miss something?

I am using Form Builder to perform the validation operation in Angular.

```
src/app/mValidation.component.html:5:42 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="saveData(userForm)">
    <div>
        Name:<input type="text" formControlName="Name"/>
        <div *ngIf="userForm.get('Name').errors" class="text-danger"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        userName:<input type="text" formControlName="userName" class="text-danger"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Email:<input type="text" formControlName="Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
    </div>
</form>
```

My Ts Page code

```
userForm:FormGroup;
  constructor(public fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm=this.fb.group({
      Name : ['',Validators.required],
      userName : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)]],
      Email : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]]
    })
   }
```

Comment: You are getting an error because of the `strictTemplate` feature of Angular.  It says `userForm.get('Name')` can be null. To solve the issue, you can use `Non-Null Assertion Operator` like `userForm.get('Name')!. errors`. Or you can use a generic and pretty cool solution with using `@ngx-validate/core`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `?` to `userForm.get`.

```
userForm.get('Name')?.errors
```